# Is there a compact set $S$ in topological semigroup $T$ with $t^{-1}K\subseteq S$, where $K$ is compact set in $T$?

Tags: topological-groups, semigroups, topological-semigroups

Let $T$ be a topological semigroup with $e\in T$ and for $t\in T$, $A\subseteq T$, define $t^{-1}A=\{r: tr\in A\}$. If $K\subseteq T$ is a compact set then $tK$ is a compact set in $T$. It seems that $t^{-1}K$ is not a compact set, in general.

Can we say that there is compact set $S$ in $T$ such that $t^{-1}K\subseteq S$?
Please help me to know it.

Comment: What is $e$? You never use it anyway.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, Thanks. $e\in T$ is identity element for semigroup $T$ i.e. $et=t=te$ for all $t\in T$.

Answer (score 1):

Not if $T$ is Hausdorff.

As it is compact in a Hausdorff space, $K$ is necessarily closed. Since the action of $t$ is continuous (definition of topological semigroup), $t^{-1}K$, the inverse image of $K$ under $t$, would also be closed. A closed subset of a compact set is necessarily compact itself. If you could guarantee such an $S$, you could prove that $t^{-1}K$ is always compact.

Comment: You need a counterexample to show that $t^{-1}K$ is not always compact. For instance if $T$ is a group, then $t^{-1}K$ is always compact.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin - The OP states that $t^{-1}K$ is not always compact, and does not question it. I limited myself to answering the question asked, without supplying information that they apparently already knew.

Comment: The OP does not really *state* that, but says *It seems that*, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T = ({\Bbb N} \cup \{+ \infty\}, \max, 0)$ equipped with the discrete topology. Let $K = \{+\infty\}$ and $t = +\infty$. Then $K$ is compact, but $t^{-1}K = T$ is not contained in any compact set.